# How to export using dynamic name for variables/functions using ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to use entierly ES6+ syntax in my current project, however, it seems there may be a drawback with ES6+ modules compared to ES5 modules.

Q1. Is there a way to export variables/functions using dynamic names, something similar to dynamic keys in objects.

```js
const externalName = 'Joeys\' Pizza'
const pizzaShop = {tel: '555-555-555'}

// ES5
exports[externalName] = pizzaShop // works 

// ES6
export const [externalName] = pizzaShop // error
```

Q2. I have some export logic that I want to reuse, so I have encapsulated it into a function. However, it seems this sort of thing may not be possible with ES6+ modules.

```js
// ES5: all good 
const exporter = db => {
  exports.first = db.collections('first')
  exports.second = db.collections('second')
}


// ES6: compiler says: Modifiers cannot appear here 
const exporter = db => {
  export const first = db.collections('first')
  export const second = db.collections('second')
}
```

Any advice, information or suggestions will be appreciated. Currently, I feel the two module syntaxes may just be treated in different ways, on the other hand, there may be work around that I'm unaware of.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to export variables/functions using dynamic names, something similar to dynamic keys in objects.

No, there is not. You need to be able to name an export, it should not be dynamic.

If absolutely necessary, export an object and put arbitrary properties on it.

> I have some export logic that I want to reuse, so I have encapsulated it into a function. However, it seems this sort of thing may not be possible with ES6+ modules.

What you did in ES5 was questionable anyway. Calling `exporter` did modify the `exports` object, calling it multiple times will cause absolute havoc.

You could replicate that behaviour by doing

```
export var first, second;
function exporter(db) {
  first = db.collections('first');
  second = db.collections('second');
}
```

or

```
var database;
export function first() {
  return database.collections('first');
}
export function second() {
  return database.collections('second');
}
function exporter(db) {
  database = db;
}
```

but it would be better if you would just create a new object instead of messing with the exports:

```
export default function exporter(db) {
  return {
    first: db.collections('first'),
    second: db.collections('second'),
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, calling the function multiple times before could have been an issue. However, this leads to a related problem that I can no longer destructor my import like:

```import { first } from './module'```

Comment: Import syntax is not destructuring. With the first two snippets, `import { first }` will still work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the esm synthax for your export with dynamic named exports, instead you can use `module.exports`:

```js
const name = 'myExport'
function fn() {
  console.log(name)
}

module.exports[name] = fn
```

This way you can import  with `import { myExport } from './myFile'`

This was usefull for us with firebase functions.